# How to Add Dynamic Data to a QML Table

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to add rows to a table from Python. I'm using a TableView described with QML.

I can't figure out how to add a model to the table, unless the model is also in QML. But I can't figure out how to add values to the model.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication



myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
context = engine.rootContext()
context.setContextProperty("main", engine)

engine.load('users.qml')

mainWin = engine.rootObjects()[0]

# Add items
userTable = mainWin.findChild(QObject, "userTable")
tableModel = mainWin.findChild(QObject, "libraryModel")
tableModel.setData(tableModel.index(0), "one")
tableModel.setData(tableModel.index(1), "one")

mainWin.show()

sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

users.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        objectName: "libraryModel"
        ListElement {
            title: "A Masterpiece"
            author: "Gabriel"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Brilliance"
            author: "Jens"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
    }

    TableView {
        objectName: "userTable"
        anchors.fill: parent
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "title"
            title: "Title"
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "author"
            title: "Author"
        }
        model: libraryModel
    }
}
```

### Edit

```
tableModel.append({'author': 'one', 'title': 'two'})

builtins.TypeError: unable to convert argument 0 of 

QAbstractListModel.append from 'dict' to 'QQmlV4Function*'
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the append method of the `ListModel` Type? (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#append-method)

Comment: "I can't figure out how to add a model to the table, unless the model is also in QML. But I can't figure out how to add values to the model." Sorry, what? What's the model type, where do you want to define it, and from which side do you want to manipulate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody answered the question yet I will suggest you to use a workaround:
Create a javascript function in qml with two arguments and add elements into to table right from QML file.

(Obviously you have to call the function from python first, but thats a piece of cake...)

P.S. If you wanna show example let me know in comment :]

EDIT: code added

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import MyApplication 1.0

QPythonBinding{
id: binding
signal addElement(string param1, string param2)
    onAddElement: {
        myModel.append({"key1" : param1, "key2" : param2})
    }
}
```

now python code

```
class QPythonBinding(QQuickItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QPythonBinding, self).__init__(parent)

    addElement = pyqtSignal(str, str)   #you call it like this  - addElement.emit("name", "value")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    qmlRegisterType(QPythonBinding, "MyApplication", 1, 0, "QPythonBinding")
    view = QQuickView()

    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: An example would be helpful :)

Comment: Example was added, you cant just copy paste run it, but it will give you the idea, how to do it.